# Como adicionar namespaces automaticamente no Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, namespace

Ao criar uma classe qualquer no C#, usando o Visual Studio, ele automaticamente adiciona o namespace, como pode ser visto abaixo:

```
namespace Aplicacao.Modelo
{
    class Cliente
    {
    }
}
```

Já no Visual Basic, ele não faz o mesmo:

```
Public Class Cliente    
End Class
```

O resultado que eu estava esperando era:

```
Namespace Aplicacao.Modelo    
    Public Class Cliente 
    End Class    
End Namespace
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer o VS fazer o mesmo pra o VB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você deve olhar esses dois caminhos:

```
\*VisualStudioInstallationDirectory*\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\*Language*\Code\*Locale*\

\*VisualStudioInstallationDirectory*\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\*Language*\Code\*Locale*\
```

O que está em entre asteriscos é variável. Obviamente que precisa procurar no local onde seu VS foi instalado (a versão vai variar ali também). O `Language` é a linguagem do *template*, em geral será `CSharp` ou `VisualBasic`, que é a que você quer. O `Locale` é um código de acordo com a língua (falada) usada, em geral é a `1033`.

Está tudo lá o que o VS pega pra iniciar alguma coisa pronta. Edite como quiser, dentro do formato. Tem que aprender as variáveis do *template*. Pode olhar como está no C# para copiar p/ o VB.NET.